# onchange difference in IE and Chrome

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, google-chrome

I'm encountering a problem with the onchange functionality. Here is a sample code:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtArrivalDate" runat="server" 
             onchange="propertyChangedByCode();" placeholder="Arrival Date" 
             class="datepicker input-small" />
```

With series of testing and investigations, I found out that onchange in chrome fires upon first load, while in IE, you have to edit a field before it fires. I need the behavior in IE to be implemented in Chrome to. Do you have any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As a simple solution, you could use a flag to indicate whether your `onchange` should be armed or not.

For example:

```
var onChangeIsArmed = !isOnChangeRunningOnLoad();

// ...

function propertyChangedByCode() {
    if (onChangeIsArmed) {
        handlePropertyChange();
    } else {
        onChangeIsArmed = true;
    }
}
```

It's quite not an elegant, let alone proficient solution, however, as a quick-and-dirty cure to your problem, it should work fine. The implementation of the functions not detailed above is up to you.